# jquery selector not working in IE6 due to uppercase id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden input field on a page

```
<div id="SomeDiv">
    <input type="text" name="ID" id="ID" value="Something"/>
</div>
```

If i use $("#SomeDiv #ID").val() in IE9 i get the value "Something" but in IE6 i'm getting undefined. If i change the id and name to lower case IE6 returns correctly. I.e.

```
<div id="SomeDiv">
    <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="Something"/>
</div>
```

Then `$("#SomeDiv #id").val()`. Notice I've not changed the case on the div id, only the input.

Anybody else come across this and a possible work around? Client is using IE6 so switching browser is not an option and I keep coming across this.

Update :

I've changed the id value from just "ID" to "WizardID" and it works in IE6

```
<div id="SomeDiv">
    <input type="text" name="WizardID" id="WizardID" value="Something"/>
</div>

$("#SomeDiv #WizardID").val()
```

I've also come across this issue with a field called "IsValid" IE6 cannot find the field at all but if i rename it "isValid" bam its found.  I suspect its a bug with jquery but doubt it will be fixed as IE6 is long past it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Kill that client

Comment: Does using `$('#ID')` instead work? IDs should always be unique.

Comment: I suppose you can't just change all the `id` attributes to lower case?

Comment: does $('#SomeDiv #id).value plain js work? also unrelated to the question why use 2 id's in the selector? $('#id') would do the job.

Comment: also is this input field special in any other way? name, input type? the name of the containing div etc? so you can use them as selectors? like using :  '$('div#Somediv>input')

Comment: The reason for using 2 ids is this is part of a much larger system using ajax etc to post back various parts of the page. I didnt want to have a different ID field for every use of the name ID other wise the backend code would be a mess.

Comment: Yes IE6 should die but alas clients still hold on to it and agreed i could change the case to lower case but i didnt want to just to fix IE6 unless i have no other choice.

Comment: Every "id" value **must** be unique. If you're not doing that, you're simply doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the html if possible:

> In Internet Explorer, if you’re trying to target an element using
>   getElementById, for some reason that browser will search the name
>   attribute of certain elements on the page, in addition to the id.

Using id="id" can also trigger a bunch of other IE issues.

Comment: Accepted answer as thats basically what i did but i'm not 100% that being called "ID" was the issue or the uppercase/lowercase was the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The best thing to do is change all id and classes to lowercase per common standards.  That way you don't apply any band-aid fixes.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with upper-case characters in "id" values.

Comment: My ids are generated based on backend code which if it where all lower case would not be quite so neat. but alas is looking like the way.

Comment: Pointy: Code towards standards, not what "used to work".  http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2  <-- refer to official documentation.

Comment: It especially needs to be considered especially on what document type the browser is attempting to render for.

Comment: @TaylorDondich What you quoted means `ID='ID'` is invalid, but `id='ID'` is still valid.

Comment: You're right.  Sorry.  Common place practice has shown that making sure all id's and classes being lowercase will avoid these issues.  Sorry, the standards don't dictate that.  But best practices has shown it works and avoids this scenario.

Comment: @TaylorDondich that's preposterous. There's absolutely no reason to restrict characters in "id" values to lower case.

Comment: @TaylorDondich—standards are fine, but you have to deal with the real world.